# Plot coth(x): Error in coth(x) : could not find function "coth"

Tags: r

can someone help me how to plot coth(x) in R.

I tried following:

```
h=function(x){coth(x)}

plot(h)
```

But there was error: Error in coth(x) : could not find function "coth".

Can somebody please help me how to fix it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
library(pracma)
#Code
h=function(x){coth(x)}
plot(h)
```

Output:

[image]

You would need the `pracma` package.